# A problem occured configuring project: ':react-native-onetrust-cmp'

Tags: react-native, one-trust

I have an issue when building android react native 0.66.4

It somehow mention 0.71, not sure what's wrong here. please help

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-onetrust-cmp'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-onetrust-cmp:implementation'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-onetrust-cmp
      > Cannot choose between the following variants of com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0:
          - debugVariantDefaultRuntimePublication
          - releaseVariantDefaultRuntimePublication
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'debugVariantDefaultRuntimePublication' capability com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.category 'library' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.libraryelements 'aar' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.status 'release' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'releaseVariantDefaultRuntimePublication' capability com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.category 'library' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.libraryelements 'aar' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.status 'release' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but the consumer didn't ask for it
```

Comment: Did you get the solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: yes but i forgot how to

Comment: The issue is fixed with one trust latest library ^202306.1.0